# Error in python Programming

Tags: python

I am having Problems with This code It says the is a invalid syntax on line 17.

```
import math    
def SA():
   side = int(input("What is the side of the square?: "))
   print("The Area of The Square is " + str(side**2) + ".")

def PA():
   hight = int(input("What is The Hight of The Parallelogram?: "))
   side = int(input("What is The side of The Parallelogram?: "))
   print("The Area of The Parallelogram is "+str(hight*side)+".")

def TA():
   hight = int(input("What is The Hight of The Triangle?: "))
   side = int(input("What is The Side of The Triangle?: "))
   print("The Area of Triangle is "+str((hight*side)/2)

def ca():
   r = int(input("What is the Radious of The Circle?: "))
   print("The Area of the Circle is " str(math.pi*r**2)

def main():
  op = input("Enter the operation You Want to do c = circle, s = square,     p = parallelogram, t = triangle: ")

  if op == "c":
      ca()
  elif op == "s":
      SA()
  elif op == "p":
      PA()
  elif op == "t":
      TA()
  else:
      print("INVALID OPERATION!")
      input("Press Enter To Continue...")
main()
```

I Would Appreciate if someone could help me out.
My Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you can explicitly indicate which line 17 is.

Comment: `print("The Area of Triangle is "+str((hight*side)/2)` and `print("The Area of the Circle is " str(math.pi*r**2)` doesn't have closing tag for print.

Comment: You should consider chose a better development environment. I mean your Editor should tell you syntax errors and also mark the right position.

Answer (score 1):

You have lot of minor syntax error. Also you must use `raw_input` instead of `input`. You find out why? Excercize for you.

```
import math


def SA():
    side = int(input("What is the side of the square?: "))
    print("The Area of The Square is " + str(side**2) + ".")


def PA():
    hight = int(input("What is The Hight of The Parallelogram?: "))
    side = int(input("What is The side of The Parallelogram?: "))
    print("The Area of The Parallelogram is "+str(hight*side)+".")


def TA():
    hight = int(input("What is The Hight of The Triangle?: "))
    side = int(input("What is The Side of The Triangle?: "))
    print("The Area of Triangle is "+str((hight*side)/2))


def ca():
    r = int(input("What is the Radious of The Circle?: "))
    print("The Area of the Circle is "+str(math.pi*r**2))


def main():
    op = raw_input("Enter the operation You Want to do c = circle, s = square,     p = parallelogram, t = triangle: ")
    print 'You have entered : ', op
    if op == "c":
        ca()
    elif op == "s":
        SA()
    elif op == "p":
        PA()
    elif op == "t":
        TA()
    else:
        print("INVALID OPERATION!")
        input("Press Enter To Continue...")
main()
```

I would suggest you to use some IDE like vim, emacs, pycharm, sublime or pyscriptor which helps you to find these syntax error/indentation error.

Answer (score 0):

Check my comments in the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math
def SA():
   side = int(input("What is the side of the square?: "))
   print("The Area of The Square is " + str(side**2) + ".")

def PA():
   hight = int(input("What is The Hight of The Parallelogram?: "))
   side = int(input("What is The side of The Parallelogram?: "))
   print("The Area of The Parallelogram is "+str(hight*side)+".")

def TA():
   hight = int(input("What is The Hight of The Triangle?: "))
   side = int(input("What is The Side of The Triangle?: "))
   # it's lack of a right bracket here
   print("The Area of Triangle is "+str((hight*side)/2))

def ca():
   r = int(input("What is the Radious of The Circle?: "))
   # it's lack of a comma and a right bracket here
   print("The Area of the Circle is ", str(math.pi*r**2))

def main():
  op = input("Enter the operation You Want to do c = circle, s = square,     p = parallelogram, t = triangle: ")

  if op == "c":
      ca()
  elif op == "s":
      SA()
  elif op == "p":
      PA()
  elif op == "t":
      TA()
  else:
      print("INVALID OPERATION!")
      input("Press Enter To Continue...")
main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the operation You Want to do c = circle, s = square,     p = parallelogram, t = triangle:
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much. I will try to get better at overlooking my work.